# Когда на ту же музыку пишут свои слова

Tags: терминология

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то специальный термин, когда на какую-то известную музыку пишется иной текст?

Скажем, вот например, знакомый написал такой текст и исполняет на манер восьмиклассницы Цоя:

```
Исб'шница

Пустынной улицей вдвоём
Из зала мы с тобой идём,
Ты капуччино пьёшь, а я молчу.

Вверху плывёт Эарендил.
Я б до зари с тобой бродил,
Но времени у нас всего чуть-чуть

М-м-м-м,
ИСБ'шница.
М-м-м-м.
```

Кавер? Нет, не кавер. Пародия? Мммм, ну такого намерения похоже не было. Ремикс - не ремикс. А есть ли вообще подходящее обозначение для подобного явления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое слово для этого: «песня-переделка».

По такому запросу такие песни можно найти в Интернете.

Пример, со страницы «[Переделки песен](https://prazdnik.fun/peredelki-pesen)» сайта [prazdnik.fun](https://prazdnik.fun/):

> **Учителям физики на мотив песни «Всё, что тебя касается»**
>
> **Куплет:**
>  Мы изучили закон Фарадея
>  И как узнать Земли притяжение,
>  Как рассчитать ускорение тела
>  И как узнать цепи
> напряжение.
>  Большие числа, большие задачи,
>  Свету и звуку в
> науке есть место.
>  И что же всё это значит?
>  Уже мы знаем, как
> мир интересен.
>
> **Припев:**
>  Всё, что частиц касается,
>  Всё, что лучей касается,
>  Физикой называется, называется.
>  Всё, что полей
> касается,
>  Всё, что всех волн касается,
>  Физикой называется,
> называется.

---

Более «научное» название «римейк»:

> **Реме́йк или риме́йк** (от англ. remake — «переделка») — выпуск новых версий уже существующих произведений искусства с видоизменением и
> добавлением в них собственных характеристик. **Чаще всего
> употребляется в музыке,** видеоиграх, кино и на телевидении (**как
> переделка** фильма, **песни, любой музыкальной композиции** или
> драматургической работы). **Ремейк не цитирует и не пародирует
> источник, а наполняет его новым и актуальным содержанием, однако «с
> оглядкой» на образец.** Может повторять сюжетные ходы оригинала, типы
> характеров, но при этом изображать их в новых исторических,
> социально-политических условиях. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA)

> **Ремейки в музыке**
>
> В русском языке ремейками в музыке называют заново записанные версии
> уже издававшихся композиций, причём ремейк может быть сделан как тем
> же исполнителем или музыкальным коллективом (хотя бы при участии
> одного из участников), так и перепет иным исполнителем, зачастую с
> переводом на другой язык. Зачастую ремейки создаются диджеями в виде
> миксов и ремиксов. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA)

Однако хочу обратить ваше внимание, что слово «римейк» обычно используют по отношению к эстрадным песням, а не переделанным песням, исполняемым в быту, на праздниках, в театре, в КВН и т. п.

Кроме того, хотя слово «remake» — английское, мне не удалось найти английского определения этого слова, как песни с переделанными словами. Возможно, оно имеет такой оттенок значения в русском языке по отношению к эстраде, когда берут, например, музыку другой песни и накладывают свои слова на неё.